# How can I set the same parameters/options for multiple objects?

Tags: manim

I started to learn how to use manin and found the following problem.

Suppose that I want the text in my video with `font="Calibri"` and `font_size=72`.

Then I have to write the following code:

```
Text("Text 1",font="Calibri",font_size=72)
```

After that, if I want to use the same style of text again, I have to write again the parameters/options of the function `Text()`:

```
Text("Text 2",font="Calibri",font_size=72)
```

So my question is, is it possible to define a variable with the parameters/options for `Text()` so I won't have to copy and paste them every time?

Something like this:

```
options={font="Calibri",font_size=72}

Text("Text 1",options)

Text("Text 2",options)
```

that would simply things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I just have to `def` a function:

```
def font_1(text):
    new_text=Text(text,font="Calibri",font_size=72)
    return new_text
```

Then to writte `"Text 1"` and `"Text 2"` with the same formate I just use the code

```
font_1("Text 1")
font_1("Text 2")
```